# RestSharp code does not work but same works in Postman rest client

Tags: tableau-api, postman, restsharp

I am using RestSharp nuget package to make http requests to endpoint. Here in my case the endpoint is the tableau server. Request is for trusted authentication and get authentication ticket as the response.

C# code that uses Restsharp library

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Logon(string url,string username)
        {
            string response = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                RestClient client = new RestClient(url);
                RestRequest logonRequest = new RestRequest("trusted");
                logonRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                logonRequest.AddHeader("charset", "utf-8");
                logonRequest.AddParameter("username", username,ParameterType.GetOrPost);
                IRestResponse restResponse = client.ExecuteAsPost(logonRequest,"POST");
                if (restResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    response = restResponse.Content;
                }
                else
                {
                    response = restResponse.ErrorMessage;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response = ex.Message;                
            }
            return Json(response);
        }
```

url: https://servername/trusted

username: username of user who does not exists

basically i am expecting a response of `-1` because that user does not exist on tableau. Same post request on Postman rest client for chrome works flawlessly. But restsharp reports `unable to connect to server`. Any thoughts ?

Reference:
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_webrequ.htm

This one works too.
https://community.tableau.com/thread/130481

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the C# code did not pick the system proxy configured on IE Browser. SO i had to specify the proxy in the web.config and it worked.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://server:port"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```